# Java fullscreen jframe with dual monitor

Tags: java, windows, jframe, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

Here my issue, I have 2 Jframe, one for controlling and one for displaying things to publics.
I need the display frame to be in fullscreen to avoid publics see things it doesn't need, and I need the controling frame to be usable on the other screen to control the display frame.

Here's my problem, today, I have no problem working this way in Ubuntu and a dual screen mode, but, in Windows 7 buisness 64 (don't try other version yet) The display frame actually goes fullscreen, but when i click anywhere outside the Display frame (control frame include), the display frame is automaticly minimize. I guest it's an issue with windows minimize maximize behaviour, but I really like to make it work.
I know a very dirty workaround, that consists in making display frame the size of my screen and position the display frame at the good coordinate.

Here's a sample code of what I do.
**To put the Displaying frame in full screen, focus the controling frame and push the key F11**. or use the menu (in french)

***GameFrame.java*** *equivalent to displaying frame*

```
package ihm;
import java.awt.Graphics;  
import java.awt.Image;  
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;

public class GameFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public GameFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")              
    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        gamePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if(backgroundImage != null){
                    g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),null);
                }
            }
        };
        votePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        countdownPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        bienvenuePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        adsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("ImproAffichage");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 179, 0));
        setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 1));

        mainPanel.setTabLayoutPolicy(javax.swing.JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

        gamePanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 168, 0));
        gamePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40, 40, 40, 40));
        gamePanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200));
        gamePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 2, 70, 70));
        mainPanel.addTab("score", gamePanel);

        votePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        votePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        mainPanel.addTab("vote", votePanel);

        countdownPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        mainPanel.addTab("decompte", countdownPanel);

        bienvenuePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        bienvenuePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        mainPanel.addTab("Bienvenue", bienvenuePanel);

        adsPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        adsPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        mainPanel.addTab("publicité", adsPanel);

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI() {

            protected int calculateTabAreaHeight(int tab_placement, int run_count, int max_tab_height) {
                return 0;
            }
        });

        pack();
     }                      


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GameFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new GameFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private static GameFrame instance;
    private Image backgroundImage;
    private Image decompteImage;
    private Image bienvenueImage;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel adsPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel bienvenuePanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel countdownPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel gamePanel;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel votePanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   


    public static GameFrame getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GameFrame();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

***ControlFrame.java***
*equivalent to controling frame*

```
package ihm;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice; 
public class ControlFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static ControlFrame getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ControlFrame();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private ControlFrame() {
        this.gameFrame = GameFrame.getInstance();
        this.gameFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 300);
        this.gameFrame.pack();
        this.gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        transitionPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jbBienvenue = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbScore = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbVote = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbDecompte = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbPublicite = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jpPlayerControl = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        mainMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jmScore = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jmiAddTeam = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiFullscreen = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiBackground = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiPointPath = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmOtherImage = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jmiVote = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiDecompte = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiBienvenue = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmiAds = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("ImproContro");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
        setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 500));
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout(25, 25));
        transitionPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 6));
        jbBienvenue.setText("Bienvenue");
        transitionPanel.add(jbBienvenue);
        jbScore.setText("Score");
        transitionPanel.add(jbScore);
        jbVote.setText("Aux votes");
        transitionPanel.add(jbVote);
        jbDecompte.setText("Decompte");
        transitionPanel.add(jbDecompte);
        jbPublicite.setText("Publicité");
        transitionPanel.add(jbPublicite);
        getContentPane().add(transitionPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        jpPlayerControl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 220, 0));
        jpPlayerControl.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
        getContentPane().add(jpPlayerControl, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainMenu.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(mainMenu);
        jmScore.setText("Score");
        jmiAddTeam.setText("ajouter equipe");
        jmScore.add(jmiAddTeam);
        jmiFullscreen.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F11, 0));
        jmiFullscreen.setText("Plein Ecran");
        jmScore.add(jmiFullscreen);
        jmiBackground.setText("image \"fond score\"");
        jmScore.add(jmiBackground);
        jMenuItem1.setText("couleur \"fond score\"");
        jmScore.add(jMenuItem1);
        jmiPointPath.setText("Icone de point");
        jmScore.add(jmiPointPath);
        jMenuBar1.add(jmScore);
        jmOtherImage.setText("Autre images");
        jmiVote.setText("image \"aux votes\"");
        jmOtherImage.add(jmiVote);
        jmiDecompte.setText("image \"fond Decompte\"");
        jmOtherImage.add(jmiDecompte);
        jmiBienvenue.setText("image \"Bienvenue\"");
        jmOtherImage.add(jmiBienvenue);
        jmiAds.setText("Ajouter image annonce");
        jmOtherImage.add(jmiAds);
        jMenuBar1.add(jmOtherImage);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
        jmiFullscreen.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F11, 0));

        jmiFullscreen.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jmiFullscreenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        pack();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        /*
         * * Create and display the form
         */        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ControlFrame.getInstance().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void jmiFullscreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        GraphicsDevice gd = this.gameFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();

        if (gd.getFullScreenWindow() != null) {
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
            this.gameFrame.setResizable(true);
            this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        } else {
            this.gameFrame.setResizable(false);
            this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getSize()));
            this.gameFrame.enableInputMethods(false);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(this.gameFrame);
        }
        refresh();
    }
    private static ControlFrame instance;
    private GameFrame gameFrame;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbBienvenue;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbDecompte;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbPublicite;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbScore;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbVote;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jmOtherImage;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jmScore;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiAddTeam;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiAds;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiBackground;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiBienvenue;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiDecompte;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiFullscreen;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiPointPath;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmiVote;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jpPlayerControl;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mainMenu;
    private javax.swing.JPanel transitionPanel;
    // End of variables declaration

    public void refresh() {
        System.out.println("refresh()");
        this.gameFrame.refresh();
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

**Edit1:**
I try to fullscreen both windows, but when a filechooser is called, the focus is lost because of the always on top behaviour of a fullscreen windows.

**Edit 2:**
I also tried to put a listener on iconified displaying jframe, but if I try to change state to NORMAL, the displaying jframe request focus, and my second frame can't be used because it lost focus

**Edit 3:**
If the display frame is not fullscreened, then it's not minimized when clicking on the controlling frame.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: My code is a bit long to make and example i'll try to enlight it. thank you

Comment: I found some idea, like set the state of my frame when it's iconified, but the problem is that I lost focus every time and I can't use my control frame anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here my own anwser to my own problem, the workaround I finally use and I think is the only not so ugly workaround I can found is to use  this code

```
private void jmiFullscreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
     GraphicsDevice gd = this.gameFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();

    if (!this.gameFrame.isResizable() ) {
        //gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        this.gameFrame.setResizable(true);
        this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    } else {
        this.gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getSize()));
        this.gameFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    refresh();
}
```

instead of this in my original example

```
private void jmiFullscreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    GraphicsDevice gd = this.gameFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();

    if (gd.getFullScreenWindow() != null) {
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        this.gameFrame.setResizable(true);
        this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    } else {
        this.gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        this.gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getSize()));
        this.gameFrame.enableInputMethods(false);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(this.gameFrame);
    }
    refresh();
}
```

So finally I'm not using the java fullscreen function and I just use some properties of my jframe to make it look like a fullscreen frame.

Hope it help some of you !!
have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47899123/8622005) might help you

I prefer the custom way u used :) and I came up with this solution
when I face the same problem but the issue is with the Java's Fullscreen API.

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.